# Fix [powerplaymanager] tag to [powerplay-manager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333051/why-my-footbalsoccer-team-was-transferred-to-another-league) created the tag wrong, without a space. Needs fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, thanks for the heads up!

This is now fixed to be [powerplay-manager](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerplay-manager).